# Setting an alpha on a pygame surface

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a GUI library with `pygame`.  I'd like to support transparent surfaces as well as transparent `rect`s.  The transparent rects work when I use `self.original_image.set_alpha(100)`.  I'm converting the pygame surface so it can accept an alpha with `surface.convert()`, however the image ends up with a black background and some distortion when I do this.  `surface.convert_alpha()` doesn't seem to have any effect.

```py
class UIComponent(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10, visible=True):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width_percent, self.height_percent = 0, 0
        self.x_offset, self.y_offset = 0, 0
        self.alignments = []
        self.original_image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.original_image.set_alpha(100)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def set_image(self, surface):
        self.original_image = surface.convert()
        self.image = self.original_image
```

What the surface looks like after `surface.convert()`
[image: This is what the image looks like when I use surface.convert()]

What the actual image looks like.
[image: This is what the image actually looks like.]

EDIT:
Request for the code that interacts with `UIComponent` to create the sword.

```py
self.slot_icon = UILib.UIComponent()
self.slot_icon.set_image(win.icon)
self.slot_icon.add_alignment(self.slot_icon.relative_width)
self.slot_icon.add_alignment(self.slot_icon.height_ratio_constraint)
self.slot_icon.width_percent = 0.03
self.slot_icon.add_alignment(self.slot_icon.center_x)
self.slot_icon.add_alignment(self.slot_icon.center_y)
```

In `win`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.s_width = 0
    self.s_height = 0
    self.screen = pg.display.set_mode()
    self.icon = pg.image.load("icon.png")
```

Comment: Can you please include the code where the sword(?) bitmap is used with `UIComponent`.

Comment: So when you call `set_image()`, it's just replacing the `self.image` with the supplied bitmap.  So none of the `set_alpha()` operations are maintained.  Am I understanding this correctly?  Is this what you intended?  Did you mean to adjust the alpha of the parameter too?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different kinds of transparency supported in pygame: colorkeys, surface alphas, and pixel alphas; and you can't easily mix surface alphas and pixel alphas

If you want to use `set_alpha` to set the transparency of the entire `Surface`, you use *surface alpha* (that means setting, well, the alpha value of the entire surface).

But the image you want to use is a PNG which uses *pixel alpha* (that means each pixel has its own alpha value); so you should call `convert_alpha` on the `Surface` after loading so the image.

If you want to change the surface alpha of such an image, there are basically two ways:

Option 1: use a colorkey

```
import pygame
import itertools

class UIComponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10, visible=True):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width_percent, self.height_percent = 0, 0
        self.x_offset, self.y_offset = 0, 0
        self.alignments = []
        self.original_image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def set_image(self, surface):
        self.original_image = surface
        self.image = pygame.Surface(surface.get_size())
        self.image.fill((1,2,3))
        self.image.set_colorkey((1,2,3))
        self.image.blit(self.original_image.copy(), (0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
    
    comp = UIComponent()
    comp.set_image(pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('sword.png').convert_alpha()))
    comp.rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
    
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(comp)
    E = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    alphas = itertools.cycle((10, 100, 200, 255))
    pygame.time.set_timer(E, 1000)
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == E:
                comp.image.set_alpha(next(alphas))
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprites.update()
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        
main()
```

Option 2: use a temporary surface and `BLEND_RGBA_MULT` to "apply" the transparency:

```
import pygame
import itertools

class UIComponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10, visible=True):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width_percent, self.height_percent = 0, 0
        self.x_offset, self.y_offset = 0, 0
        self.alignments = []
        self.original_image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def set_image(self, surface):
        self.original_image = surface
        self.image = self.original_image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def set_alpha(self, alpha_value):
        tmp = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
        tmp.fill((255, 255, 255, alpha_value))
        self.image = self.original_image.copy()
        self.image.blit(tmp, (0, 0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
        
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
    
    comp = UIComponent()
    comp.set_image(pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('sword.png').convert_alpha()))
    comp.rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
    
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(comp)
    E = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    alphas = itertools.cycle((10, 100, 200, 255))
    pygame.time.set_timer(E, 1000)
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == E:
                comp.set_alpha(next(alphas))
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprites.update()
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        
main()
```

The result is the same:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that I am resizing the surface in another method every time that the display changes size:  `self.rect.width = win.s_width * self.width_percent`
`self.image = pg.transform.smoothscale(self.original_image, self.rect.size)`.  So `image` is getting changed when I change the scale of the surface.